# Passing var from outside react - build error

Tags: reactjs

Im passing some variables from outside of my react app (create-react-app) and it works fine on front end but I get build errors in webpack/npm? Because the variable doesn't exist (or it doesn't know about it).

I have this var in a  var preloadTab = "x"; in my .net page

```
49:31  error    'preloadTab' is not defined                   no-undef
54:14  error    'preloadMsg' is not defined                   no-undef
```

I tried putting an undefined check around it but think its just flagging that instead now:

```
 if (typeof preloadMsg !== 'undefined') {
     if (preloadMsg != ""){
       console.log(preloadMsg, "preloadMsg")
         this.setState({preloadMsg: preloadMsg})
     }
  }
```

Whats the best way to pass a variable from outside the react "ecosystem" outside of an ajax call?

Comment: you could reference it via `window` or you could pass the variable to the component as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can make use of either `getInitialState` or by setting `defaultProps` for the component. Would either of those work for your case?

As azium already stated in a comment, another option would be to pass the data in as a prop. If you don't have access to the component, then you can save it as a global value either via `window` or using a constants file. Having a constants file is common in React apps and I would suggest this route over using `window`.